# Android: Converting a URI to File

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that allows users to create backup files and then re-import them with a file chooser. I export the file using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("application/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.FILE_CHOOSER);
```

The code returns a URI in onActivityResult():

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == Constants.FILE_CHOOSER) {
         Uri uri = data.getData();
    }
```

I have a `File` that references a file within my app's local storage that contains data. I would simply like to take the file from the app's internal storage and save it to whatever directory the user selected. I can't get it to work. How do I convert the returned `Uri` into a `File` so I can write data more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would simply like to take the file from the app's internal storage and save it to whatever directory the user selected

The user didn't select a directory. The user is creating a document, where the `Uri` points to that document.

> How do I convert the returned Uri into a File so I can write data more easily?

You don't, any more than you convert an HTTPS URL into a `File` so you can write data more easily.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to open an `OutputStream` on the (empty) document created by `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and identified by the returned `Uri`. Then, use standard Java I/O to copy the bytes from your file (e.g., via a `FileInputStream`) to the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Do you have some example syntax or a good resource to look at? I can't seem to find any info on the Android developer pages.

Comment: @wdavies973: For what? `ContentResolver` is a Java class. You typically get an instance of it by calling `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`, such as your activity. `openOutputStream()` is a method on `ContentResolver`. You pass in the `Uri` as a parameter. You get an `OutputStream`. So, combined, that is `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(data.getData())`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Appreciate your help.